# Length of diagonals in a cyclid quad

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry

I am working on contest math papers and I am struggling to recall this elementary result:

Show that in a cyclic quad $ABCD$ where $A$ and $C$ are right angles, $AC=BD \sin \angle D$.
[image]

Comment: Produce AO to cut the circle at C'. Join CC'. Consider the triangle ACC'.

Comment: AC/sinD =(law of sines for ACD)= AD/sinACD =(the same arc)= AD/sinABD =(law of sines for ABD)= BD/sinBAD = BD

Comment: BD is the diameter $=2R$. By extended law of sines $AC = 2R\sin \angle D = BD \sin \angle D$.